# Order by the newest post date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 
f_type.`id` AS type_id,
f_type.`name` AS type_name,
f_thread.`id` AS thread_id,
f_thread.`uid`,
f_thread.`title` AS thread_title,
f_thread.`hits`,
u.`username`

FROM `forum_type` AS f_type
LEFT JOIN `forum_thread` AS f_thread
ON f_type.`id` = f_thread.`type_id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u
ON u.`id` = f_thread.`uid` 
LEFT JOIN `forum_posts` AS f_posts
ON f_posts.`type_id` = f_thread.`id`    

WHERE f_type.`id` = '".$_GET['type_id']."'
ORDER BY f_posts.`date` DESC
") or die (mysql_error());
```

It's about a forum and I want the threads to be sorted like checking which post is the newest in this forum.

I use forum_type (f_type) as a sub-category of forum, which is the top-category. So it's hierarchy is like this list:

1. forum
2. forum_type
3. forum_thread
4. forum_posts

And like in the query I've written in the code, I wanted to order by the newest post date... but it doesn't order by that. I don't know actually what it's ordered by... can't see a scheme. I guess this problem's caused, because of these multiple joins, but I'm not sure.

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you might want to group by threads and select the maximum post date for each thread if you want to list threads.

```
SELECT 
f_thread.`id` AS thread_id,
f_thread.`uid`,
f_thread.`title` AS thread_title,
f_thread.`hits`,
u.`username`,
max(f_posts.date) as last_post_date

FROM `forum_thread` AS f_thread
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u
ON u.`id` = f_thread.`uid` 
LEFT JOIN `forum_posts` AS f_posts
ON f_posts.`type_id` = f_thread.`id`    

WHERE f_thread.type_id = ".$_GET['type_id']."

GROUP BY thread_id
ORDER BY last_post_date DESC
```

Hope that helps. f_posts.type_id is a bit suspect, maybe there's a thread_id instead in the table?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. I think this post was correct in the first place.

Comment: Still, it doesn't work that way. Sadly. Are there too many joins or the wrong type of joins maybe?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do... if you want to list the threads in each forum type separately you probably don't want to join with the types, but instead select the types first and then select the threads in separate queries. But that has nothing to do with it, the query should work, thing is I'm just guessing the schema, so unless you're more descriptive there's much more I can suggest.

Comment: The scheme I'm aiming for is like the forum at www.php.de . I'm in the view of "forum_type" which is named "Support" for example. The top-category of this forum_type is the "forum" table, which is named "General Discussions" for instance. So, I'm currently in the overview of all threads in "Support". I just want to order the displayed threads by the newest date of each post in each thread. I dont know how I could be more descriptive... but I'm trying to. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I edit my response, you should probably not query about the forum type there, if you want that info make a separated query is my advice. Other than that, if it doesn't work, can you tell what's the output of your query or what error message do you get? If you get nothing try setting ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); before the query

Comment: Thank you! Finally it worked. I'd to edit the "ON f_posts.`type_id` = f_thread.`id`" part to "ON f_posts.`thread_id` = f_thread.`id`". As a last question... someone mentioned I'm doing the wrong kind of joins if I join LEFT. Why is that?

Comment: Nothing wrong with left joining. Left join means in this case for example, if there is no user for that uid, or there are no posts for that thread id then you'll still get a thread record, but you'll get null values for those columns (username and last_post_date). With an inner join you'd not get those records at all. In theory, those cases should never happen so there'd be no difference.